# Column, Row and Date as Logical Operator

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheets with a Column (I) that is filled with dates. When a date in the column is *older* than today, I need the corresponding row A to I to shift to a *red background*.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional format

1. Select Cell A1 (or lower if you have headers)
2. Select Conditional Format in the menu
3. In range add    :I
4. Choose  Formula
5. Fill in    =I1

   Choose red background

Answer (score 0):

Please try clearing formatting from and selecting ColumnsA:I and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=$I1<today()
```

Then select red fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

If your dates include times (whether or not displayed) then a 'today' date will not be formatted even if time 'now' is after your the time of your 'today' data.

Comment: Excellent! Solved the problem! I added the formula =$I2<today() and that seemed to fix one minor problem, namely that row 2 (Row 1 is header) came up blank when I added the formula =$I1<today(). I did not clear all formatting first, because there was quite a lot of it, and I didn't want to format everything from scratch.

I also needed Column N to be formatted the same way as A:I, so I added A2:I200,N2:N200 to the range.